# Creating box plots by looping multiple columns

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to create multiple box plot charts for about 5 columns in my dataframe (df_summ):

```
columns = ['dimension_a','dimension_b']

for i in columns:
    sns.set(style = "ticks", palette = "pastel")

    box_plot = sns.boxplot(y="measure", x=i,
                          palette=["m","g"],
                          data=df_summ_1500_delta)
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)

    medians = df_summ_1500_delta.groupby([i])['measure'].median()
    vertical_offset=df_summ_1500_delta['measure'].median()*-0.5

    for xtick in box_plot.get_xticks():
        box_plot.text(xtick,medians[xtick] + vertical_offset,medians[xtick],
                     horizontalalignment='center',size='small',color='blue',weight='semibold')
```

My only issue is that they aren't be separated on different facets, but rather on top of each other.

[image: screenshot]

Any help on how I can make both on their own separate chart with the x axis being 'dimension a' and the x axis of the second chart being 'dimension b'.

Comment: If you want to draw multiple boxplots, use catplot to draw them. Please refer to the official [reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw two boxplots next to each other at each x-position, you can use a `hue` for `dimension_a` and `dimension_b` separately.  These two columns need to be transformed (with `pd.melt()`) to "long form".

Here is a some example code starting from generated test data. Note that the order both for the x-values as for the hue-values needs to be enforced to be sure of their exact position. The individual box plots are distributed over a width of `0.8`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dimension_a': np.random.choice(['hot', 'cold'], 100),
                   'dimension_b': np.random.choice(['hot', 'cold'], 100),
                   'measure': np.random.uniform(100, 500, 100)})
df.loc[df['dimension_a'] == 'hot', 'measure'] += 100
df.loc[df['dimension_a'] == 'cold', 'measure'] -= 100

x_order = ['hot', 'cold']
columns = ['dimension_a', 'dimension_b']

df1 = df.melt(value_vars=columns, var_name='dimension', value_name='value', id_vars='measure')
sns.set(style="ticks", palette="pastel")
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df1, x='value', order=x_order, y='measure',
                 hue='dimension', hue_order=columns, palette=["m", "g"], dodge=True)
ax.set_xlabel('')
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)

for col, dodge_dist in zip(columns, np.linspace(-0.4, 0.4, 2 * len(x_order) + 1)[1::2]):
    medians = df.groupby([col])['measure'].median()
    vertical_offset = df['measure'].median() * -0.5
    for x_ind, xtick in enumerate(x_order):
        ax.text(x_ind + dodge_dist, medians[xtick] + vertical_offset, f'{medians[xtick]:.2f}',
                horizontalalignment='center', size='small', color='blue', weight='semibold')
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplots for two columns]